# Boolean Operators on Tags aren't working as advertised

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, new-nav

These boolean operators may need some work... or clarification.

This is what shows up after a real-time notification for [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20and%20not%20javascript):

[image: Boolean search fails for <code>and not</code>]

Comment: You can't circle the absence of something, but that second question isn't tagged [java] either.  Maybe it's actually xor?

Comment: Seems to be working now

Comment: please also use links to share your bugs, we need to make sure that the internal state is consistent

Comment: @Sklivvz added. It seems to be working now, though

Comment: was it a real time notification by any chance?

Comment: yes. It was. I did update the tab after real-time notification and that was what I got... But it seems fixed now...